# Check if a value is between two columns, spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, one with my data and another one to compare. What I want to do is check if a value is in a range of two different columns, for example:

```
Df_player
    +--------+-------+
    | Baller | Power |
    +--------+-------+
    | John   |   1.5 |
    | Bilbo  |   3.7 |
    | Frodo  |   6   |
    +--------+-------+

Df_Check
    +--------+--------+--------+
    | First  | Second | Value  |
    +--------+--------+--------+
    |   1    |   1.5  |  Bad-  |
    |   1.5  |   3    |  Bad   |
    |   3    |   4.2  |  Good  |
    |   4.2  |   6    |  Good+ |
    +--------+--------+--------+
```

The result would be:

```
Df_out
    +--------+-------+--------+
    | Baller | Power | Value  |
    +--------+-------+--------+
    | John   |   1.5 |  Bad-  |
    | Bilbo  |   3.7 |  Good  |
    | Frodo  |   6   |  Good+ |
    +--------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a join based on a between condition, but note that `.between` is not appropriate here because you want inequality in one of the comparisons:

```
val result = df_player.join(
    df_check, 
    df_player("Power") > df_check("First") && df_player("Power") <= df_check("Second"), 
    "left"
).select("Baller", "Power", "Value")

result.show
+------+-----+-----+
|Baller|Power|Value|
+------+-----+-----+
|  John|  1.5| Bad-|
| Bilbo|  3.7| Good|
| Frodo|  6.0|Good+|
+------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) ! And if I want to put Value in the column Power selecting in the DF just Baller and Power (that contains now the column Value)?

Comment: You can replace the select line with `.select(col("Baller"), col("Value").as("Power"))`

Comment: But this tell me that column "final_value" doesn't exit. This is because is not in DF_player, right?

Comment: Sorry, I would want to say "Value"

Comment: It should work because the column value is in df_check, which is joined. You see, in my answer, "Value" is selected successfully. I think there might be some other problems in your code. It would be helpful if you could show your code by editing your question.